# Centos 6 Email Server email not receiving but can send

Tags: linux, postfix, sendmail, dovecot

well iam new to setting up mail server in my vps and this strange issue comes up.

I have domain and setup mx records in domain registry. but i cannot receive email in my server but can send email from SquirrelMail.

I checked telnet serverip 25 and port 110 but connection for 25 connection refused.

```
[root@server ~]# telnet 199.175.51.215 110
Trying serverIP ...
Connected to serverIP .
Escape character is '^]'.
+OK Dovecot ready.
quit

Connection closed by foreign host.
[root@server ~]# telnet serverIP 25
Trying 199.175.51.215...
telnet: connect to address serverIP : Connection refused
```

I checked netstat -plnt command and here is the out; and port 25 is used by send mail and assigned for localhost ip.

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      613/sendmail
```

i have mx.domain.com record in my domain registry.

in main.cf; inet_interfaces = all

Please let me know some solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem seems to be that sendmail is already binding to one of the addresses you told postfix to bind to (localhost), which is likely preventing postfix from starting smtpd.

You don't mention what distro you use, but I would possibly start by running:

`sudo systemctl stop sendmail` or `sudo service sendmail stop`.

Then try restarting postfix, and if that works, prevent sendmail from starting on boot (using `systemctl disable` or `chkconfig`).

I would strongly recommend you *not* provide unencrypted access to your pop3 server, in passing - it would be preferrable to completely block access to tcp/110, and use pop3s (tcp/995) instead.